# Handling Button Enabling Via jQuery When 3 Form Areas Need to Have Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After some reconfiguring I have some jQuery that handles enabling a "save" button when a field has a value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.save-button').attr('disabled', true);
  $('#selection').keyup(function () {
    if ($('#selection').val().length != 0) {
      $('.save-button').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('.save-button').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

... but I realize now I should only enable this button when three separate form elements have values -- two of which are input fields, and one being a text-area.

The thing is, these could be filled in in any order, so how do I get my check to run so as to make sure it enables the "save" button when all three have values? In other words, what event can I use to check this?

The three IDs in question are: `selection`, `schedule`, and `json-data`

Here is my relevant HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Job Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="job-name form-control" id="selection">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div><label for="meeting-time">Schedule</label></div>
  <input type="datetime-local" class="job-schedule form-control" min="getDateDefault()" max="getEndDate()"
    id="schedule">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Repeat Every</label>
  <input type="text" class="job-repeat-every form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Job Data (json)</label>
  <textarea class="job-data form-control" id="json-data">{}</textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-success save-button" data-action="save">Save</span>
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-warning" data-action="cancel">Cancel</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should use the **focusout** event on each element you need to check its value.
>
> I have created a snippet, you can see the updated version of your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('.save-button').attr('disabled', true);

    $('#selection, #schedule, #json-data').focusout(function () {

        if ($('#selection').val() == "" ||
            $('#json-data').val() == "" ||
            $('#schedule').val() == ""
        ) {

            $('.save-button').attr('disabled', true);

        } else {

            $('.save-button').attr('disabled', false);

        }

    });

});
```

```css
.btn[disabled="disabled"] {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Job Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="job-name form-control" id="selection">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div><label for="meeting-time">Schedule</label></div>
  <input type="datetime-local" class="job-schedule form-control" min="getDateDefault()" max="getEndDate()"
    id="schedule">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Repeat Every</label>
  <input type="text" class="job-repeat-every form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Job Data (json)</label>
  <textarea class="job-data form-control" id="json-data">{}</textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-success save-button" data-action="save">Save</span>
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-warning" data-action="cancel">Cancel</span>
</div>
```

Comment: With a little configuring this works. Many thanks, @Hamid!